# Time Series Forecasting using Custom Representation

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima, stochastic-processes

Let's assume that I have a background knowledge of some stochastic nondeterministic process and I identified the process to be autoregressive and follow some irregular pattern:

$z_t = \sum_{i=1}^N \phi_iz_{(t-fib(i+1))}$ for some $N>0$

where $fib(i)$ returns $i$-th fibonacci number.

Is there any model that can fit these kind of (custom?) models? Or should I just fit **ARIMA**($N,d,0$) model and hope that $\phi_k$'s for $z_{t-k}$'s where $k\notin\{ fib(i) \,\, \forall i\in\mathrm{N}  \}$ will turn out $0$?

Comment: @CagdasOzgenc Thank you, that was an oversight on my part. It's fixed now.

Comment: Since N is finite this is and ARIMA model with some lags with 0 coefficients. You may directly specify the non-zero entries and estimate it.

Comment: @CagdasOzgenc Thanks a lot, this answers my question.

Comment: Good software packages let you specify the not only max-lag, but also individual non-zero items so that computer will not spend time on those 0 entries.

Comment: I've already checked the ARIMA model in R and, indeed, it offers a `fixed` parameter where I can set mask on the parameters. You've been very helpful.